# consonant deletion in list

Tags: python, string

I am working on a function that receives an input string (st) and a character (ch). The string st may  have letters, digits and symbols.  The function should return a new string, which has the same vowels (any of ‘aeiou’ or ‘AEIOU’) that the original string has, and in the same positions as in st , and for the other positions it should have the symbol ‘$’, but only including these characters  until and not including the first appearance of the character ch (even if ch is a vowel) . (The string being returned may be shorter than the original string, possibly the empty string as well).

I have turned the string into a list in order to change the characters that aren't vowels into the symbol '$', but I do no understand how to make this change. Here is what I have tried,

```
def vowels_or_not (st, ch)
    newst=list(st)
    n= st.find('ch')
    nt=n+1
    sign='$'
    con=list('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz')
    for con in newst:
        del con
        del newst[nt:]    
    return sign.join(newst)
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: rather than defining the consonant list, you should have a list of vowels and then everything else is a consonant.

Comment: can you show some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to delete things out of `newst` when the problem definition says that the vowels have to be *in the same position*, and other positions should have '$'. In other words, there's no deletion to be done here, just replacement.

Comment: So should: `somefunc('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog', 'z')` return `'$$e $ui$$ $$o$$ $o$ $u$$e$ o$e$ $$e $a'` ? (I've assumed spaces don't get replaced)

Comment: (The more I read the OP's code the more I'm wondering whether he's even went through a basic Python tutorial. Otherwise, how could someone expect `for x in y: del x` to do anything?!)

Answer (score 2):

A less "loopy" approach:

```
def vowels_or_not(string, char):
    left, mid, right = string.partition(char)
    # left is now a string with everything BEFORE the first occurence of char

    left = [(c if (c.lower() in "aeiou") else '$')
            for c in left]
    # left is now a list of all characters in the original left with vowels 
    # replaced with $

    return ''.join(left)

print vowels_or_not('abcdefghijklmno', 'i') 
# => a$$$e$$$
```

Comment: (Generally if you're using `del` a lot in Python you're probably doing something wrong.)

Comment: +1 for a working answer that hopefully the OP can use step by step and learn from

Answer (score 0):

You want to pick a different variable for iterating through the for loop, say: `con`, then for the list of constonants, say `cons`. I picked those two names since they have some meaning through the plural in cons implying that its a list rather than a single element. If you pick the same variable then you are redefined con to be equal to this element in the string, rather than the list of consonants.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach:

```
def func(st,ch):
   con='bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
   vow="aeiou"
   sign="$"
   ans=""
   for x in st:
       if x !=ch:
           if x in con:
              ans+="$"
           else:
              ans+=x   
       else:
           break
   return ans

print func("abcdeefhkfgosdmvnsvh","k")
print func("adbfkjsdbksdbv","a")
print func("iduskjfhdrsqksd","j")
```

**output:**

```
a$$$ee$$

i$u$$
```

Answer (score 0):

[itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is you friend.

Using the itertool function takewhile it became a simple oneliner, not even worthy of a function.

```
st = "printing until k and not over"
ch = "k"

from itertools import takewhile
"".join( c if c in 'aeiouAEIOU' else '$' for c in takewhile(lambda k: k!=ch,st) )
```

The takewhile iter trough the string while the character is different from the given one, and the iterated character are substituted if not vowels.

Comment: With enough determination you can turn almost anything into a one-liner, as long as said line can be of arbitrary length and abstruseness.